# RF signal on Audio/Music/Guitar equipment

Tags: rf, audio, emc, emi-filtering, frequency-modulation

It is looking like the standard RF noise from my (new to me) old apartment wiring through my amp to my speakers. Suspected it could be due to poor guitar shielding/grounding, bad cables etc. Started removing variables to determine the source of the interference.

- New cables, Ernie ball;
- Peavey Vypyr VYP II guitar amp, new and noise-free anywhere else;
- Pair of studio monitors, also noise-free at my old house;
- All guitar/bass hardware shielded and working fine.

**The scenario:**

1. There is LoS from my room window and the FM station antenna, which I am almost clearly listening to;
2. This old building has no grounding, 2-wire phase+neutral installation;
3. Occurs on my guitar amplifier and my studio monitors, both have internal power supplies.
4. Doesn't occur on my TV soundbar or my other computer speakers, both with external DC power supplies;
5. The "reconstructed" audio signal from the FM radio has constant volume, does not respect volume knob, does not need a cable hooked on the input.
6. Noise is weaker farther from the window but still present.

**Not possible:** install grounding or moving from this room to another.

**Question:** What can I do to eliminate or mitigate the problem with my equipment that is sensitive to the FM signal?

Could a product like this [Stabilized Insulator Module](https://www.sms.com.br/produtos/estabilizadores/modulo-isolador/modulo-isolador-progressive-iii-500-va?aba=especificacoes), which claims to have galvanic isolation, work?

**Findings:**

1. Radio signal keeps playing after completely disconnecting from the AC (amp running for a moment on supply capacitors);

Comment: If the building has no grounding, are you sure that 1) you're actually providing useful shielding to your audio setup (it should be grounded!) and 2) the building is actually up to code? Depending where you live, it's possible that your landlord should have had the house rewired *ages* ago to be properly grounded, and they may now be in violation of the building code.

Comment: Does the guitar amp play FM radio even when it is not connected to anything (no guitar, no wires, just mains)? If this is the case, try unplugging it. It might keep running for maybe a second on its supply capacitors, which is long enough to notice if it is still playing FM radio when unplugged from mains.

Comment: If it *doesn't* keep running on its supply capacitors, you can also try @bobflux's suggestion by using one of those emergency backup batteries, if you have one. Or a generator, but you're less likely to have one of those.

Comment: @Hearth, 1) Yes, everything works flawless in other envinroments. 2) This is a 10-story tall building from the 70s, my landlord owns only 1 unit and doing anything would only be possible on the wiring inside my apartment, here in Brazil, regulation about up-to-date electrical installation seems to be respected only in new buildings.

Comment: @Daniel My 1) is not about the environment, it's that the shielding you're applying relies on having a ground to actually work. If you can electrically connect it to something grounded (maybe the electrical conduit, maybe some plumbing), you might see improvements.

Comment: @bobflux, that was a great idea, FM keeps playing unchanged, after unplugging from the outlet (no physical connection or switch).

Comment: What could be the culprit that makes my soundbar and another speaker, with external DC bricks, dead quiet regarding noise?

Comment: OK so it's the internal circuit picking up RF and turning into a receiver, not related to mains. When you say the studio monitors pick up noise, are they connected to the amp, or do they both pick up noise independently? Another test: with the amp only connected to mains (no other cables) plug in headphones. Do you get the same noise in the headphones as you did in the loudspeaker? ([link to schematics](http://zorkmids.com/?p=384))

Comment: Here's [the schematic](https://imgur.com/a/vwcZm5X). If noise comes out the headphone jack AND the loudspeaker/amp, then it's probably being picked up by the opamps on the left. If it only comes out from the loudspeaker but not the headphones then it's after this in the signal chain. Another test is to see if the amp can apply guitar effects to the noise. If yes it is picked up before the effects, otherwise after. Also there's this PA_MUTE which mutes the output of this schematic sheet, it's probably controlled by a button, can you see what it does?

Comment: @bobflux, headphone output being used, speaker muted as intended, clearly listening to the radio on headphones (both sides). Master volume raises radio volume. Audio seems to be mono but I could be wrong (quality is awful).

Comment: @bobflux, on headphones, guitar effects are applied to the radio signal.

Comment: @bobflux, the studio monitors (bookshelf speakers) comprise of 2 units, one has an internal supply, amplifier, eq, etc. the other has only that old regular clip wire terminal. Back from main unit: https://www.windys.com.br/wp-content/gallery/b77/2.jpg

The other one is passive https://www.windys.com.br/microlab/b77/

Comment: @bobflux, another finding, the main monitor running alone has close to zero noise but I can hear something really really close (1cm from speaker), hooking up the passive side increases noise. It is a shitty audio cable made of 2 parallel wires without any shielding mesh or whatever. Just two sleeved copper wires inside another bigger sleeve.

Comment: ...and the cable is 3m long which is close to the wavelength of FM? OK so the guitar amp applies DSP effects to the radio, that's creative! Looking at the schematics (DSP board page 1) I see guitar input at top left, goes through a few opamps, through ADC (CS4270 chip in the middle)-DSP-DAC, to guitar distortion (IT_GAIN to transistors on the bottom) then back into ADC-DSP-DAC, then opamps to poweramp and headphone output. This has a USB port, so that probably allows you to record on a PC, can you check if it records the noise on the guitar input?

Comment: I mean try to see if you can record with/without distortion applied, if you can get it to record the guitar input directly that narrows it down to just the input opamps basically.

Comment: @bobflux, guitar effects AND radio coming through the USB recording. Radio always present and effects applied ontop of radio+guitar signal. The cable between the bookshelf speakers is 1.8m long (2 wires in parallel).

Comment: Looking at the [schematics for the VIP2](http://zorkmids.com/?p=384) there's an input board with an opamp, but it has filtering caps. You did not plug a cable into the input jack, and I doubt the jack itself is large enough to be a good antenna at FM frequencies. So it's probably not that opamp. Maybe it's the cable between the input jack and the DSP board that works as antenna. If you look at the schematic for the DSP board, there is no EMI protection where the cable meets the board.

Comment: You could try a clamp-on ferrite core on the cable between the input jack and the DSP board. This could also maybe work on the cable between your loudspeakers. If that works it means the whole cable is acting as antenna in common mode. If the guitar input jack metal shell is not connected to the metal chassis with the usual nut then you could try connecting it. If it removes the noise but you get hum instead then you can use a cap instead of a direct connection.

Comment: Also you can try making contact between the two halves of the metal chassis at various places with a screwdriver. I see on online pics there's a foam gasket to prevent it from rattling, but that foam is not conductive, so you have two shells that appear to make a shield but don't. For the enclosure to be a good shield it has to be reasonably continuous. So if you create a temporary connection between the two metal shells with a screwdriver and you get a change in the noise, it's time to get some conductive gasket or just add more screws...

Comment: You could also put a filter cap on the DSP board. Any of these may work... or not, that's the problem, no guarantees !

Comment: Useful, going to try a mix that is at my disposal right now and report later. Time to go shopping for parts. I was going to replace the bookshelf cable for this one, https://loja.conduscamp.com.br/produto/cabo-aft-2x22-awg-blindado-em-malha-de-cobre-estanhado-preto/5415670?idSku=5422003, maybe will rewire everything with that.

Comment: @bobflux, which values should I try for those capacitors (jack metal shell - chassis, dsp board)? Where in the DSP board? Also going to try connecting the 2 halves together later today.

Comment: For the jack you can try 1nF, with connections as short as possible between jack ground and metal enclosure. The idea is to short RF to the enclosure at the point of entry. For the DSP board input the problem is that the output of the opamp on the jack board drives the cable directly, so if you put a cap there, it will be at the output of the opamp, which may make it oscillate. The usual value would be a SMD 100pF C0G ceramic cap soldered on the back of the input connector (it should fit between the pins)

Comment: (between signal and ground) but it would be better with a low value resistor like 50 ohms in series with the output of the opamp to isolate it from the cap. Maybe you can add the resistor to the input jack board by cutting a trace... or just get 2 IDC connectors and a bit of ribbon cable, cut the wire, and put a thru hole resistor in the middle: that would make a replacement input cable with the resistor in it. I hope the simpler stuff works though.

Answer (score 0):

Years ago I had the same problem with the stereo amplifier of my younger brother. I solved it by shielding all cables *inside the amplifier* by wrapping them in aluminum foils and connect these foil to the chassis of the amplifier. Indeed this kind of noise is induced on the inner cables by time varying magnetic fields (they could due to radio transmission or to leakage field of transformers).